# Why compiler does not allow us to use `var` instead of `generic type`?

Tags: c#, generics, var, generic-type-argument

In the example code below `Generic Type` is used in writing a Reverse function that reverses an array of any type:

```
public T[] Reverse<T>(T[] array)
{
    var result = new T[array.Length];
    int j=0;
    for(int i=array.Length; i>= 0; i--)
    {
        result[j] = array[i];
        j++;
    }
    return result;
}
```

However, I could write the same code like below by using `var` type:

```
public var[] Reverse(var[] array)
{
    var result = new var[array.Length];
    int j=0;
    for(int i=array.Length; i>= 0; i--)
    {
        result[j] = array[i];
        j++;
    }
    return result;
}
```

However, the compiler does not accept the latter. I want know to the difference between `Generic type` and `var`?

Comment: generic is runtime and var is compile time

Comment: `var` is not a type. `var` is a keyword that let's the compiler infer the type. It's not the same as a generic at all.

Comment: @sLw: _generic is runtime and var is compile time_ Generics are handled by the compiler. There is no run-time overhead or "late bound" semantics when using generics.

Comment: @MartinLiversage That's not true.  You can absolutely distinguish between a generic operation and a non-generic version (with the appropriate type substitutions) at runtime.  The runtime is aware of the idea of generics and uses them, and there can be some overhead.  Generics allow you to write statically typed code, such that that lots of statements can be made at compile time about what the code can and can't do, but it's not a strictly compile time language feature.  `var` on the other hand is something the runtime doesn't even know about. It has no idea what variables did or didn't use it.

Comment: @Servy: If there are some details I missed in my statement _There is no run-time overhead or "late bound" semantics when using generics._ I would be really happy to learn about these. I realize that "run-time overhead" and "late bound semantics" are a bit vague terms.

Comment: @MartinLiversage I specifically mentioned that generics allow for static typing.  I never claimed that it resulted in anything being dynamically bound.  You said that it's it's handled by the compiler, and not the runtime, which isn't true.  The runtime knows about generics, it's built into the compiled code, and the *runtime* is responsible for handling many aspects of generics, rather than the compiler (things that the compiler would be doing if you did all of the substitutions manually at compile time).  It is a feature implemented through *both* the compiler and runtime.

Comment: @MartinLiversage If you want to see an example of a feature that's *actually* strictly a compile time feature, then you can look at `var`, as mentioned, which is an *entirely* compile time feature; the runtime has no knowledge or impact on its implementation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It doesn't compile, so it doesn't work.

The use of generics and the `var` are very different. `var` means "compiler, I'm lazy, please discover for me the single exact type that I should use here, inferring it from what I'm writing after the =" (there are some cases where it is mandatory to use `var` instead of writing explicitly the variable type, but we will ignore them) ... So for example

```
var foo = "Hello";
```

The `foo` variable type is `string`, because the compiler can infer it by looking at the type of the expression after the assignment `=`. The `var` is totally replaced by the "correct" type in the compiled program.

So it would be equivalent to writing:

```
string foo = "Hello";
```

Generics instead are a way to make a method/class able to adapt to different types that are used in calling/creating them. In this instance the caller could

```
int[] foo1 = Reverse(new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
```

or

```
long[] bar1 = Reverse(new long[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
```

The compiler (because generics are resolved at compile time) will infer the type `T` (`int` or `long`) from the parameters used and will write it somewhere (in the compiled file). The runtime then will see this and create two different specialized versions of `Reverse` (one for `int` and one for `long`). But in this case `T` is an "openness" to the various possible types of parameters. In the case of `var`, there is a single possible type that the variable can be. So in the compiled file there is a `Reverse<T>` compiled method, while at runtime there are a `Reverse<int>` version of the method and a `Reverse<long>` version of the method (and if necessary the runtime will create other versions of the method).

Using `var` as a parameter wouldn't have any meaning, and it would be a poorer syntax than the generics one, where the list of used generics are put somewhere (between the method name and the `(` in this case) and you can have multiple generic types, like

```
public static IEnumerable<TResult> Select<TSource, TResult>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, TResult> selector)
```

(that is the LINQ `Select`) where there are two generic parameters `TSource` and `TResult`. With your syntax you wouldn't be able to differentiate between the two generic parameters (there is a single `var` keyword), and you couldn't use `var` as is currently used (compiler, I'm lazy, please discover for the the type of this local variable).

Comment: You've used the word "desume" a couple of times, but I don't know what that means?

Comment: You can't make meaningful statements about what the effects would be of code that doesn't compile.  If Microsoft decided to make that syntax valid for some reason there are any number of possible features that they could actually be using it to implement, these claims that this is what it would do in a fictional world where this was a real feature aren't meaningful.

Comment: "The runtime then would see this and create two different specialized versions of Reverse" is only true for value-types. Reference-types share the same run-time generic class/method.

Comment: I'm interested in "desume" too. Websters has "to select or borrow" but that doesn't seem quite right. Is it perhaps a back-formation by analogy with "assume", meaning "to reach a *non*-ex-recto conclusion"?

Comment: Bad translation from italian. Desumere in italian is to deduce/to infer.

Comment: @Enigmativity I was very precise on what I wrote, while trying to simplify it while omitting some details... You have opened the can of worms (why value types have different specializations while reference types share the same specialization), so you can explain it :-)

Comment: @Servy Yes, I can make a meaningful statement about what the OP "meant" to write by looking at its question. But the finer point was "what is the difference between `var` and `<T>`"?

Comment: @xanatos You can make statements about what you think the OP wants to do, sure, but you're making statements about what C# would do in a fictional world where a language feature exists that doesn't exist, and you can't make statements about how that non-existent feature would act, because *it doesn't exist*.

Comment: @Servy I wasn't inferring what the syntax would mean if implemented... But I used the wrong english form (and the wrong verbale tense... in the end I was writing about what `var` is and what generic are... I've added an annotation about why its syntax would be "poor" if implemented.